# Viewing Streaming videos in media wiki

Tags: php, video, mediawiki

I have to view the videos in media wiki pages. I have tried with some of the extensions like embedded video. But those are only allow us to view the videos from some of the service providers. I want to view the streaming video in the mediawiki page with my own flash player and also it should support all formats. Is that possible with media wiki extensions?

Answer (score 2):

Use [TimedMediaHandler](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TimedMediaHandler): it's much better than crappy players relying on flash, because it uses an HTML5 free software player. See [blog post about its usage on Wikimedia projects](https://blog.wikimedia.org/2012/11/08/introducing-wikipedias-new-html5-video-player/).

Comment: Thank you nemo. It will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you using [jwPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/) its a very good video player and support both flash & HTML5, I've been using it for sometime already and I like really like it, beside the free version contains all the functionality's of the payed one

The have a very good documentation and their API contains all you may need in controlling your media streaming (both audio & video)

Regarding the video format support they have almost every thing you might think of.

#### some useful links:

- [Features](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/features/)
- [Configuration wizard](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/wizard/): for an automatic code generation
- [Media Format Support](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28836/media-format-support/)

and there is much more, they have plugins for some famous CMS, and you can find support to integrate it your media wiki if there is not a ready to use solution

I hope this would help

Comment: yes of-course JW player is good for viewing the videos but i need to display my own custom player in the mediawiki page. Not other players.Is there any media wiki extension for that

Comment: What do you mean by `my own custom player ` ? would you like to develop a brand new player ?

Comment: yes i already developed a player by using the flex.I want to view that player in the media wiki pages

Comment: Okay, I see, perhaps you better include this information, to your question, otherwise I would still suggest you to used the `jwPlayer` and create you own skin it would be better for performance, and creating a skin does not take lot of effort

Comment: I already mentioned about that "my own flash video player". and i am not looking for skin changes. Have to do lot of functionality changes too like external interface,getting the video from my streaming server etc.,

Comment: okay, I see now better your need, unfortunately I cannot help with that

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain you can make custom tags for MediaWikia. I managed to find this link I hope it is helpful.

> http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Tag_extensions

In theory you could create your own tag and program your video player into it.